# how to make django channel comsumer to send reply asynchronously

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

in my consumer, I write several reply_channel.send

```
> def ws_message(message):    
>     line = get_output()
>     message.reply_channel.send({
>         "text": line,
>     })
>     line = get_output()
>     message.reply_channel.send({
>         "text": line,
>     })    line = get_output()
>     message.reply_channel.send({
>         "text": line,
>     })
```

And I found that the consumer did not send these three replies until the last message.reply_channel.send is executed.

What can I do to make it send a reply immediately when each reply_channel.send is executed?

I did this because I have a program generating an output at a random interval. If I use the code above, the webpage will wait until the full result arrives and it's quite unfriendly for users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass immediate=True to the send argument.